# Form with nested attributes with a has_one association not working in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-forms

I'm tring to set values for two models that have a has_one association using accepts_nested_attributes_for, but nothing in the fields_for is being shown on the view.

I have confirmed the same code works on Rails 2.x, and it works fine when its a has_many.
Code below.

Model

```
class Parent < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :child
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child
end

class Child < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :parent
end
```

Controller

```
def new
    @parent = Parent.new
    @parent.build_child
end
```

View

```
<%= form_for @parent do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <% f.fields_for :child do |builder| %>

    <%= builder.label :childname %>
    <%= builder.text_field :childname %>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

..And after copying that and looking at it, that's a horrible class name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In rails 3 you should use (notice the equal sign in `<%=`):

```
<%= f.fields_for [...]
```

instead of :

```
<% f.fields_for
```

same goes with form_for

Comment: Thanks that did the trick. Didn't think it was something that simple.

Comment: Typo - should be f.fields_for