# Nested Attributes not Working in Rails Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, rails-models

I have a form that uses two models - badge and badge winners. The user_id and community_id fields are needed for badge_winners which is nested in badges.  I was trying to learn from Ryan Bates' Railscast (http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

The error I'm getting is:

```
ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in BadgesController#create
unknown attribute: user_id
app/controllers/badges_controller.rb:42:in `new'
```

Line 42 corresponds to this line in :create

```
@badge = Badge.new(params[:badge])
```

here's the controller:

```
def new
  @badge = Badge.new
  badge_winner = @badge.badge_winners.build
  respond_with(@badge)
end

def create
  @badge = Badge.new(params[:badge])
  if @badge.save
    flash[:notice] = "Badge was successfully created."
    redirect_to home_path
  else
    flash[:notice] = "There was a problem creating your badge."
    redirect_to home_path
  end     
end
```

Here's the form (both community_id and user_id are populating fine):

```
<%= form_for(@badge) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :Description %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>

  <%= f.fields_for :badge_winners do |builder| %>
     <%= builder.hidden_field :user_id ,:value => user_id %>
     <%= builder.hidden_field :community_id ,:value => community_id %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit "Give Badge" %>
<% end %>
```

The models (user_id and community_id are fields in the BadgeWinner table):

```
class Badge < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :community
  has_many :badge_winners, :dependent=>:destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :badge_winners
end

class BadgeWinner < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :badge
end
```

This is a similar problem, but I don't have the syntax cause:
[Form with nested attributes with a has_one association not working in Rails 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4087742/form-with-nested-attributes-with-a-has-one-association-not-working-in-rails-3)

I'm hoping someone's able to help.  I just know it's a newbie error somewhere.  Thanks in advance for any assistance!

Comment: What is `user_id` set to on this line `<%= builder.hidden_field :user_id ,:value => user_id %>`?

Comment: Do you have the column `user_id` in your table?